# Bindfs ignores user in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, debian-wheezy, fstab

I'm trying to mount a directory under a specific user:group combo. Using bindfs on the command yields the expected results:

```
root@system:~# bindfs foo bar --user=fooz --group=baz
root@system:~# ls -lha bar
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x  6 fooz baz   4.0K Nov 19 12:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root  4.0K Dec  2 10:22 ..
```

However, when trying to make this persistent through /etc/fstab:

```
root@system:~# grep bar /etc/fstab
/root/foo   /root/bar   fuse.bindfs user=fooz,group=baz 0   0
root@system:~# mount bar
root@systen:~# ls -lha bar
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root baz   4.0K Dec  2 12:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root  4.0K Dec  2 12:17 ..
```

For some reason, bindfs seems to ignore the user option when I mount the system via an fstab definition. How can I fix this?

- Debian 7.8
- bindfs 1.10.3

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in more recent versions the `user` and `group` options are deprecated and replaced with `force-user` and `force-group`. The more recent version seems to work fine on other machines running the exact same commands. Because of dependency issues, I'm not going to try and fight Debian package repositories. I have found a working workaround.

I'm not tagging this as answered, as someone else might have a better idea or an actual solution.

Comment: you could mark this as the correct answer tested and veryfied. Funny thing as they are no longer documented but still working in CLI